# preserve multiple whitespaces in BASH for loop

Tags: bash, unix

I am writing a script that removes vowels from a string while preserving sequential white spaces, here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

result=""
for (( i = 0; i < ${#1}; i++ )); do
  [[ "${1:$i:1}" =~ [^aeiouAEIOU] ]] && result+="${1:$i:1}"
done
echo $result
```

It executes properly for example:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ bash remove_vowels.sh "Hi it's me"
H t's m #vowels removed successfully
```

But when my argument contains multiple white spaces:

```
[user@localhost ~]$ bash remove_vowels.sh "Hi it's     me"
H t's m #Whitespaces are gone
```

What do I need to change so my code work as desired?

Comment: Shorter: `tr -d 'aeiouAEIOU' <<< "Hi it's     me"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double quote your variable to prevent the shell from applying word splitting on its contents:

```
echo "$result"
```

Search for "word splitting" in `man bash` for the details.